# Tag wiki excerpt edit review misleads about allowed formatting

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, usability, tag-wiki-excerpt

I just [rejected an edit for an incorrect reason](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8381421) because I thought it was removing perfectly correct links with a bogus reason (“formatting”), whereas it was actually removing Markdown syntax that doesn't work in excerpts.

The review page for an excerpt edit claims that the only diff mode available is “markdown”. This is misleading, because the text is in fact not Markdown. Therefore:

- The diff mode should be labeled something other than “markdown”; perhaps something like “excerpt text” or “plain text”.
- The diff should be rendered **in normal font, not monospaced**; this provides a visual cue that what you're looking at is what will be seen, not “source” that will be further interpreted.

Comment: That's still a lengthy excerpt

Comment: @random That's beside the point, but for precision I'll say that I rejected it _for an incorrect reason_, not that I was incorrect to reject it.